# Where do wordpress posts go?

Tags: posts

We have wordpress installed in our data center and it manages all the content in our corporate website.  So I have a list of pages that are accessible and available in tree view.  We are interested in also posting to a regular blog as a part of our corporate website.

I'm not clear how to do this but I noticed a New Posts option in the very top nav.  I so I created a couple draft posts. However, now I can't find them.  I foudn a video that discussed saving draft posts, but my left hand nav does not show any link to posts... just pages.  So I can create new posts but have no idea how to manage them.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Please, specify weather you're not seeing what Milo's answer is showing (backend), or if you can't locate them in the frontend site (which would be a matter of using the right [template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Templates))...

Answer (score 3):

You should have a Posts menu item, like Pages. If it's not visible, there is possibly code in your theme, or a plugin hiding the menu item. Look through your plugins and their options, and/or switch to a default theme to determine where this is happening.

[image: menu]

Comment: yea, that Posts section is what I don't see. We're using it for CMS for our site, so I'm a tad nervous to mess with settings / templates /themes in fear of causing our site or homepage to no longer display.  I have a CMS and CMS Tree Page View, and SEO installed.  My guess is it's the CMS supressing it.  In consulting with someone else on this, they suggested if I want to create a real blog, best option is to standup another instance of wordpress and use the static page setting, so as to not mess with the site.

Comment: that seems really unnecessary, you'll have to maintain two different installs. I think a better option is to mirror the site on a staging server and make changes there without fear of taking your live site down. then you can sync the staging site with live once you've made changes. there are many questions/answers on this site regarding setting up a development environment. you could do it on a local machine with mamp/wamp, etc..